# How to create two different regression line based on factor for each facet? R, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, linear-regression

I am trying to create two different lines based on exercise = 0 or exercise = 1 for each facet (by gender). The first code is without facet_wrap and the two lines based on gender are different. The second code is with facet_wrap and the two lines seem to be the same line. How can I change the code so that the two lines are different within each facet?

```
ggplot(cdc, aes(weight,wtdesire, color = exercise, group = 
interaction(gender,exercise))) + geom_point(alpha = 1/5) + 
geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(linetype=exercise))
```

produces: [facet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN1R1.png)

However, when I add facet_wrap the two lines for each facet seem to be the same.

```
ggplot(cdc, aes(weight,wtdesire, color = exercise, group = 
interaction(gender,exercise))) + geom_point(alpha = 1/5) + 
geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(linetype=exercise)) + facet_wrap(~gender)
```

produces: [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOEW3.png)

Comment: You probably need to use just `group = exercise ` in the second plot.

Comment: @LoBu I tried that too but it didn't change anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@LoBu solution is correct. Here's an example using mtcars data:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, group=interaction(vs, am))) +  
       geom_point(alpha = 0.2) + 
       geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(linetype=as.factor(vs)))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, group=vs)) +  
       geom_point(alpha = 0.5) + 
       geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(linetype=as.factor(vs))) +
       facet_wrap(~am)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I made a mistake of grouping by as.factor instead of the continuous variable.